# Can google maps be used for non-GPS related features, such as providing a game map?

Tags: java, web-applications, google-maps

Wasn't sure whether this belongs here or on Game Development...

Would it be possible to use Google Maps as a map for a game? For example, creating a multiplayer online game; instead of designing my own map, would it be possible to use a real world map provided by Google? For example have my game set in the USA?

Does the Google maps API provide any functionality to restrict which countries can be seen or have waypoints etc marked on?

I'm assuming that the above can be done by simply plotting co-ordinates, but I'm wondering if there is anything that would prevent this slightly un-conventional use of the maps API.

Comment: you can limit the bound using google map API, and i've seen a couple times that you can limit the visibility of the map as well.  I am not sure on the usage, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is best answered by reviewing the [Google Maps API FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html). In particular, you might want to take a look at the "Understanding the Terms of Service" section.

It depends on the specifics of your game, but in general, you should be OK.